# Normalise style attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, wdio-v5

In IE11 when we `block.getAttribute('style')` we return

```
border-bottom-width: 1pt; border-bottom-style: dotted; border-bottom-color: rgb(10, 49, 132)
```

But in chrome it returns `border-bottom: 1pt dotted rgb(10, 49, 132)`

How do I get the IE11 to return the same as chrome?

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? Please provide the related **html and css code** and clarify which element's style do you want to get. So that we can have a test and see how to help. We don't know what `block` mean in your code and what does the actual style look like in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think is this in IE11

```
block.style.border-button
```

Because is only information "border-button"

Answer (score 0):

Both browsers have different default styles for page elements. Use this default from Chrome: https://gist.github.com/ambidexterich/34828a904dd97dd2a345